# C# Main menu options button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, monogame

I am creating a game with a group of people in my class and my job is to create a main menu, I have created a simple main menu, now I would like to link or navigate my buttons. The buttons that I have created are Play, Options and Exit. I firstly want to mainly sort out the options menu and be able to click on it so I will be able to create like credits or a how to play guide etc.

Comment: Don't know what your needs are. You should add some specific description. And please refer to [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to break your game into individual screens/classes, here is a link to the game state manager sample.

https://github.com/nkast/XNAGameStudio/tree/master/Samples/Game-State-Management